# Privacy. How to prevent transaction recipient tracing prior transactions of mine

Tags: transactions

I am thinking of sending some BTC to a new BTC address, but do not have complete trust in that new one.

I'm sending to someone else, but want to be sure that if I do, they can't access other people I have used the same BTC wallet to send BTC

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you sending to someone else or to another address that you own? Also, what do you mean by not having complete trust in it? Do you not trust the owner of the new address?

Comment: I'm sending to someone else, but want to be sure that if I do, they can't access other people I have used the same BTC wallet to send BTC.

Comment: So you are asking about financial privacy? By sending a tx, you don't want the recipient to learn about your past transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider finding a reliable [Bitcoin Tumbler (Bitcoin Mixer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency_tumbler).

But be aware that you are placing trust in a third party, especially for custodial mixers. Some people have lost money to fraudulent mixers. I would do my research into a company very carefully before risking using them.

Some wallets have mixing capabilities built in to them. These may be a better option.

One example of an article on the subject is [How to Mix Your Bitcoins Using Coinjoin for Greater Privacy](https://news.bitcoin.com/how-to-mix-your-bitcoins-using-coinjoin/) -- but I can't vouch for the correctness of this article. I suggest taking the time to do your own research.